# How to make sure the user knows interactivity of this widget

Tags: ios, flutter, user-interface, design-patterns, interactive

I want to keep the interface as clean as possible, but I want the user to know, that they can edit the exercise (eg the list tiles with the not-so-dark background), where I then display the exercise in big, with options to delete and so on.

I don't want to color the exercise name blue and make it a button, also I have thought about putting in a little pencil icon on the far left, but this would take away from the aesthetic I think.

The solution probably has to with coloring something in blue, but I am not sure what, does anybody have any ideas or input?

[image: this is the ui in question]

Answer (score 2):

You can make it glow, by using the `BoxShadow` widget:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxShadow-class.html